# Legitimate Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-upgrade, legal

I have been trying to get the update to install windows 8.1 on my sistem without luck. While searching I realized my Windows 8 is pirated. I tried to contact the computer shop who installed it but they are out of business and cannot contact anyone.

I tried to buy a legitimate copy from the windows website but it is IMPOSSIBLE! the website says "Get the free update" however I cannot as my windows is pirated.

My question is, I want to make my copy of Windows 8 legal and upgradable to Windows 8.1. How can I purchase a legal copy without losing my data on my computer?

---

**UPDATE**

Below is the system screen. There are no option as to change the product key. 
[image]

Comment: Open cmd.exe, then type `slui 3` then ENTER to change the product key, if you have a valid one.

Comment: Contact MS: 1-800-RU-LEGIT, they'll help you get legit. :)  Also check out http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/piracy/reporting/faq.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use <kbd>win key</kbd> + <kbd>pause/break</kbd>

At the bottom of that  page there is a change product key option. Enter the Legit product key there. Most computer stores will have a licence available. If you need it quick there may be some ebay sellers who will open the box and email you the key ?

The MS site itself isnt very helpful

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I cannot see such option. Please see my screenshot in the update. Also, non of the links on this page lead to such a window that allows me to change it. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be the bottom of a page similar to this one http://www.winvistatips.com/attachments/77d1204728377t-disable-automatic-restart-automaticrestart1.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately not. None of the tabs under advanced settings (or any other window that has a link to it from this window for that matter) offers me such an option. Gosh am I the only person with a pirate software spending hours to make it legitimate and not even its manufacturer cares? :)

Comment: It shouldnt be on advanced settings its on the main page which shows the specs at the bottom